# Prove that the partial trace is a quantum operation, finding its Kraus representation

Tags: mathematics, textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, linear-algebra, kraus-representation

I am referring to Nielsen and Chuang Quantum Computation and Quantum Information 10th Anniversary Edition Textbook, Chapter 8.3.

A linear operator $E_i:H_{QR}\longrightarrow H_Q $ is defined by:

$$E_i \bigg(\sum_j \lambda_j |q_j\rangle|j\rangle    \bigg)\equiv \lambda_i |q_i\rangle$$

whereby $|q_j\rangle$ and $|j\rangle$ are arbitrary states of system Q and the basis of system R respectively. Define $\varepsilon$ to be the quantum operation with the operation elements {$E_i$}:

$$\varepsilon(\rho)\equiv \sum_i E_i \rho E_i^{\dagger}$$

The text went on to say:

$$\varepsilon(\rho\otimes|j\rangle\langle j'|)=\rho \space \delta_{j,j'}=tr_R(\rho\otimes|j\rangle\langle j'|)$$

Question:
I do not understand how to arrive at $\delta_{j,j'}$, and what form will be the operator representation of $E_i$ take? From what I've observed, system Q and R are not entangled in the last equation and $E_i$ seems to disregard whatever $|j\rangle$ basis of system R. 
Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the presentation in N&C is a little confusing because $\rho$ is used in two contexts. I'll substitute one of those for a $\sigma$.

You can define
$$
E_i=I\otimes\langle i|,
$$
which will certainly achieve the effect stated in your first equation. This lets us define the quantum operation
$$
\mathcal{E}(\sigma)=\sum_iE_i\sigma E_i^\dagger
$$
where $\sigma$ is a density matrix on $QR$.

Now, let $\rho$ be a density matrix on $Q$. We have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}(\rho\otimes|j\rangle\langle j'|)&=\sum_iE_i(\rho\otimes|j\rangle\langle j'|)E_i^\dagger\\
&=\sum_i(I\otimes\langle i|)(\rho\otimes|j\rangle\langle j'|)(I\otimes|i\rangle)\\
&=\sum_i\rho\otimes\langle i|j\rangle\langle j'|i\rangle\\
&=\sum_i\rho\otimes\delta_{i,j}\delta_{j',i}\\
&=\rho\otimes\delta_{j,j'}\\
&=\rho\delta_{j,j'}
\end{align}

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Say $\lambda_j=\delta_{j,k}$ so that the first equation gives:
$$
E_i\left|q_k\right>\left|k\right>=\delta_{k,i}\left|q_i\right>
$$
Now, we can write $\rho$ as:
$$
\rho = \sum_k p_k \left|q_k\right>\left<q_k\right|
$$
so that
$$
\varepsilon(\rho\otimes\left|j\right>\left<j'\right|)=\sum_i\sum_k p_k E_i \left|q_k\right>\left|j\right>\left<q_k\right|\left<j'\right|E_i\dagger = \sum_{i,k}p_k\delta_{j,i}\delta_{j',i}\left|q_k\right>\left<q_k\right|
$$
This term is non-zero only when both kronecker deltas are 1 which happens only when $i=j$ and $i=j'$, which is only possible when $j=j'$. This gives us the required
$$
\varepsilon(\rho\otimes\left|j\right>\left<j'\right|)=\delta_{j,j'} \sum_k p_k \left|q_k\right>\left<q_k\right| = \rho \delta_{j,j'}
$$